# How to generate correlation plot of my data.frame in R?

Tags: r, plot, correlation, pearson

It might be a simple question.
I have a df and I want to generate a correlation plot for my data in R.

```
head(df)

            x  y
1 -0.10967469  1
2  1.06814661 93
3  0.71805993 46
4  0.60566332 84
5  0.73714006 12
6 -0.06029712  5
```

I've found a package called **corPlot** and I've generated two plots based on pearson & spearman methods.

```
corPlot(df, method = 'pearson')
corPlot(df, method = 'spearman')
```

here is my output with pearson method:

[image]

I wondered if there is another package to generate the same correlation plots that I am not aware of?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Yes, but maybe you can explain what your problem with the current plot is?

Answer (score 3):

There is another library corrplot

```
library(corrplot)
cor.table = cor(df)
corrplot(cor.table)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the corrplot library, here is an example from this [link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/corrplot/vignettes/corrplot-intro.html)

```
library(corrplot)
M <- cor(mtcars)
corrplot(M, method = "circle")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check out **`?pairs`**. It's great for doing scatterplots for combinations of variables, but varying the type of graph that is displayed on the

1. **lower triangle** (pass function taking 2 variables to `lower.panel` argument)

   - *e.g., `pairs(df, lower.panel=points` for a scatter plot*
2. **diagonal** (pass function taking 1 variable to `diag.panel` or `text.panel` argument)

   - *this is tricky! see help file for how to do a histogram*
3. **upper triangle** (pass function taking 2 variables to `upper.panel` argument)

   - *e.g., `pairs(df, upper.panel=function(x,y)text(0,0,cor(x,y)))`, but **see below***

**Scatter plot and correlation, from help file (`?pairs`):**

```
panel.cor <- function(x, y, digits = 2, prefix = "", cex.cor, ...)
{
    usr <- par("usr"); on.exit(par(usr))
    par(usr = c(0, 1, 0, 1))
    r <- abs(cor(x, y))
    txt <- format(c(r, 0.123456789), digits = digits)[1]
    txt <- paste0(prefix, txt)
    if(missing(cex.cor)) cex.cor <- 0.8/strwidth(txt)
    text(0.5, 0.5, txt, cex = cex.cor * r)
}
pairs(USJudgeRatings, lower.panel = panel.smooth, upper.panel = panel.cor)
```

**With your data, do the following:**

```
pairs(df, lower.panel=plot, upper.panel=panel.cor)
```

I love that function, and use it myself as-is. It might look a little odd with only an `x` and a `y`, but